# More performant way of conditionally filling in values in one data frame using second data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization, purrr

## Background

I'm working with two [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble)s. `dta_miss_dates` has approximately 200K rows and consists of integer and character vector. The character vector is derived from a date using `format.Date(x, "%Y%m")`. The character vector has approximately ~ 20% of missing values.

### Task

The task is to populate the missing values using values available in `dta_all_dates` [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble). That tibble has approximately ~ 7 million rows. The filling algorithm works as follows:

1. For each id with missing date `var_id_miss` a corresponding id is matches in table with all the dates `var_id_all`.
2. Function summarising the value is then deployed. Most commonly this is `max` but the solution has to be sufficiently agnostic to incorporate other functions, like `min` or `median`.

### Problem

The solution outlined below uses `map_chr` from [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package. To deploy the summary function on a subset corresponding to the given id. This gives the desired flexibility is too slow to be deployed on the actual data.

## Example

### Data

For the example data to resemble the actual conditions the **`reduce_example_date <- TRUE`** should be set to `FALSE`.

```
# Settings ----------------------------------------------------------------

# Libraries
library("tidyverse")
library("stringi")
library("progress")

set.seed(123)

# Tibble sizes
# Reduce sample sizes for faster development
reduce_example_date <- TRUE # FALSE reflects actual experiment settings

nrow_missing_dates <- 2e5
nrow_all_dates <- 7e6

if (reduce_example_date) {
  nrow_missing_dates <- nrow_missing_dates / 100
  nrow_all_dates <- nrow_all_dates / 100
}


# Sample data with missing dates
dta_miss_dates <- tibble(
  var_id_miss = sample(1e6:9e6, nrow_missing_dates, replace = FALSE),
  var_dts_miss = sample(c(
    seq.Date(
      from = Sys.Date() - 2 * 365,
      to = Sys.Date(),
      by = "day"
    ),
    rep.int(NA, 100)
  ), nrow_missing_dates, replace = TRUE)
) %>%
  mutate(var_dts_miss = format.Date(var_dts_miss, "%Y%m"))

# Data with all dates
dta_all_dates <- tibble(
  var_id_all = sample(dta_miss_dates$var_id_miss, nrow_all_dates, TRUE),
  var_grp_sth = stri_rand_strings(
    n = nrow_all_dates,
    length = 3,
    pattern = "[A-D]"
  ),
  var_dts_all = sample(
    seq.Date(
      from = Sys.Date() - 50,
      to = Sys.Date(),
      by = "day"
    ),
    nrow_all_dates,
    replace = TRUE
  )
)
```

### Matching

```
# Matching Functions ------------------------------------------------------

match_via_purr <-
  function(id_col,
           dta_dates,
           search_fun,
           date_coll,
           verbose) {

    # Iterates over IDs and where date is missing conducts a search
    f_match <- function(id_obs) {

      filter(dta_all_dates, var_id_all == id_obs) %>%
      summarise(across(.cols = {{date_coll}}, .fns = {{search_fun}})) %>%
        pull({{date_coll}}) %>%
        format.Date(format = "%Y%m")

    }

    pb <- progress_bar$new(total = length({{id_col}}),
                           format = "[:bar] :current / :total (:percent) ETA: :eta")

    map_chr(.x = {{id_col}}, .f = ~ {pb$tick(); f_match(id_obs = .x)})
  }
```

### Test

```
dta_miss_dates %>%
  mutate(var_dts_miss = if_else(
    is.na(var_dts_miss),
    match_via_purr(
      id_col = var_id_miss,
      dta_dates = dta_all_dates,
      search_fun = max,
      date_coll = var_dts_all
    ),
    var_dts_miss
  ))
```

### Problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using base R `merge`. I think you should prepare your summarized lookup table ahead of time, rather than calling it repeatedly within a vectorized loop. {dplyr} is fairly fast, but there are some known performance hits, and you can relatively easily write things that do a lot more work than they need.

This reprex below "fills" your data set in about 30 seconds on my machine, whereas the ETA for the {purrr} based approach you had was 5ish hours.

```r
# Settings ----------------------------------------------------------------

# Libraries
library("tidyverse")
library("stringi")
library("progress")

set.seed(123)

# Tibble sizes
# Reduce sample sizes for faster development
reduce_example_date <- FALSE # FALSE reflects actual experiment settings

nrow_missing_dates <- 2e5
nrow_all_dates <- 7e6

if (reduce_example_date) {
  nrow_missing_dates <- nrow_missing_dates / 100
  nrow_all_dates <- nrow_all_dates / 100
}

# Sample data with missing dates
dta_miss_dates <- tibble(
  var_id_miss = sample(1e6:9e6, nrow_missing_dates, replace = FALSE),
  var_dts_miss = sample(c(
    seq.Date(
      from = Sys.Date() - 2 * 365,
      to = Sys.Date(),
      by = "day"
    ),
    rep.int(NA, 100)
  ), nrow_missing_dates, replace = TRUE)
) %>%
  mutate(var_dts_miss = format.Date(var_dts_miss, "%Y%m"))

# Data with all dates
dta_all_dates <- tibble(
  var_id_all = sample(dta_miss_dates$var_id_miss, nrow_all_dates, TRUE),
  var_grp_sth = stri_rand_strings(
    n = nrow_all_dates,
    length = 3,
    pattern = "[A-D]"
  ),
  var_dts_all = sample(
    seq.Date(
      from = Sys.Date() - 50,
      to = Sys.Date(),
      by = "day"
    ),
    nrow_all_dates,
    replace = TRUE
  )
) 

# pre-calculate ID summaries based on search_fun

prepare_data <- function(dat, id_col, date_coll, search_fun) {
 dat %>%
  group_by({{id_col}}) %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = {{date_coll}}, .fns = {{search_fun}})) %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = {{date_coll}}, format.Date, format = "%Y%m"))
}

# prepare a lookup table, using desired summary function
system.time( {
  lut <- prepare_data(dta_all_dates, var_id_all, var_dts_all, max)

  # identify missing indices
  na_idx <- which(is.na(dta_miss_dates$var_dts_miss))
  
  # fill missing indices, merge on ID
  dta_miss_dates[na_idx, 'var_dts_miss'] <- merge(dta_miss_dates[na_idx,], lut, 
                                                  by.x = "var_id_miss", 
                                                  by.y = "var_id_all", 
                                                  all.x = TRUE, sort=FALSE)$var_dts_all
} )
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  31.721   0.176  31.935

any(is.na(dta_miss_dates$var_dts_miss))
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can probably make the data preparation even faster using {data.table} to cook down your big table. Something like:

```r
library(data.table)

prepare_data2 <- function(dat, id_col, date_coll, search_fun) {
  data.table(dat)[, .(var_dts_all=search_fun(.SD[[date_coll]])), by=c(eval(id_col)), .SDcols = c(eval(date_coll))]
}
system.time(lut2 <- prepare_data2(dta_all_dates, "var_id_all", "var_dts_all", max))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  7.248   0.095   6.991
```

Comment: Note that prefiltering `dta_all_dates` using `na_idx` (as e.g new arg to `prepare_data`) would  reduce the amount of data to search/summarize ahead of time -- at the cost of lost information about the non-NA IDs.